# Wamp not starting, port 80 already in use

Tags: apache, wamp, port80

The problem is simple, my wamp icon stays orange. I tried restarting Wamp several times, restarting my laptop and even uninstalling skype, but it doesn't work.

When I test port 80 it says this:

```
Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.19
```

What do I do?

Comment: What to do? Read all the answers already available here on SO. See the "Related" section on the right hand side...

Comment: This is not my first time here, and I know how searching works. Couldn't find a suitable answer, so that's why I asked what to do

Comment: OK. If really none of the existing answers helped (there are about 5 different typical issues addressed in the answers, a short look showed), then you will have to tell us what potential issues you already ruled out and what makes your situation different. Otherwise all we obviously can do is point you to those "typical issues". It also certainly is worth a try to connenct to port 80 on your system by using a plain `telnet` client. What you will see is technical gargle, since you will see the raw protocol of whatever service listens on that port, but it might give you a valuable hint...

Comment: Well, it seemed that the problem was, that another guy used the laptop for his own project. He changed alot of settings so that Wamp stopped working. A simple reinstall fixed the issue. Still, thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: @arkascha That is **not an error** That is saying that Apache has started and is using port 80. **That is what you want!!** If the WAMPServer icon is Orange then it is a **MYSQL** issue

Comment: _You can lead a man to an error message,_ ___but you cannot make him read it___

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, issue seemed to be solved by a reinstall